# Java implicit call of toString() when using the "this" keyword

Tags: java, methods, this, tostring, implicit

I have two classes, ThisTest and SimpleTime. The method buildString() returns a concatenated string with the "this" keyword. When I run it, "this" seems to refer to the method toString() and not the class SimpleTime. Why does the toString() method execute when I use the "this" keyword? Thanks.

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

import javax.swing.*;

public class ThisTest {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SimpleTime time = new SimpleTime( 12, 30, 19 );

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, time.buildString(), 
       "Demonstrating the \"this\" Reference", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

        System.exit(0);
    }
}

class SimpleTime {
    private int hour, minute, second;

    public SimpleTime( int hour, int minute, int second )
    {
        this.hour = hour;
        this.minute = minute;
        this.second = second;
    }

    public String buildString()
    {
        return "this.toString(): " + this.toString() + 
        "\ntoString(): " + toString() + 
        "\nthis (with implicit toString() call): " + this;
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        DecimalFormat twoDigits = new DecimalFormat("00");

        //"this" not required, because toString does not have
        //local variables with same names as instance variables
        return twoDigits.format( this.hour ) + ":" +
        twoDigits.format( this.minute ) + ":" +
        twoDigits.format( this.second );
    }

    public String anotherString()
    {
        return "Another String for you";
    }
```

}

Comment: Do you know what `this` is? Do you know about `String` concatenation?

Comment: What were you expecting to happen?

Comment: I understand what String concatenation does and what "this" is, but I didn't understand why toString was being called when I used "this".

Comment: I didn't know what to expect really

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because that's what happens when you use the String concatenation operator (`+`).

It calls the `toString()` method of the object being added (which is guanateed to be there since it's defined in `Object`).

In your case, that's the current object (`this`) so you get `this.toString()` called. And because you've overriden `toString()` in your class, you get the result of that.

**Edit to add:** Note that there's no difference between `+ this` and `+ this.toString()`; you'll end up with the same result.

Specifically, this is covered by [section 15.18.1 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1)

> If only one operand expression is of type String, then string conversion (§5.1.11) is performed on the other operand to produce a string at run time.

And [§5.1.11](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.11) states:

> ...
>
> Now only reference values need to be considered:
>
> If the reference is null, it is converted to the string "null" (four
>   ASCII characters n, u, l, l).
>
> Otherwise, the conversion is performed as if by an invocation of the
>   toString method of the referenced object with no arguments; but if the
>   result of invoking the toString method is null, then the string "null"
>   is used instead.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense. What would happen if I didn't have a toString() method in the class?

Comment: @inventorbc If you don't override `toString()` you get the default implementation from `Object` which outputs a combination of the hashcode and class name.

Comment: Oh so thats what that is... I kept getting SimpleTime@22c73b when I took out the toString() method. Thanks man!

Answer (score 2):

The expression

```
String s = "literal" + object;
```

compiles to

```
String s = new StringBuilder().append( "literal" ).append( object ).toString();
```

If we have a look at the source code for `StringBuilder#append(Object)`, we find:

```
public StringBuilder append(Object obj) {
    return append(String.valueOf(obj));
}
```

If we have a look at the source code for `String.valueOf(Object)`, we find:

```
public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
}
```

So ultimately, the object's `toString()` method is called.

Blatantly plagiarising from DavidWallace's comment:

Section 15.18.1 states

> ... If only one operand expression is of type String, then string conversion (§5.1.11) is performed on the other operand to produce a string at run time. ...

and section 5.1.11 states

> ... the conversion is performed as if by an invocation of the `toString()` method of the referenced object with no arguments; but if the result of invoking the `toString()` method is null, then the string "null" is used instead. ...

So it seems the current JDK doesn't *directly* adhere to the JLS, but it gets there in the end.

Comment: Your last sentence is false.  It is _absolutely_ part of the JLS that this happens.  Section 15.18.1 states "... If only one operand expression is of type String, then string conversion (§5.1.11) is performed on the other operand to produce a string at run time. ..." and section 5.1.11 states - "... the conversion is performed as if by an invocation of the toString method of the referenced object with no arguments; but if the result of invoking the toString method is null, then the string "null" is used instead. ..."

Comment: Hmm.  I wish I'd bothered to read Brian Roach's answer before I went and found those two excerpts for myself.  :-(

Comment: @DavidWallace Interesting. Bad Oracle for not following the JLS. I'll put a note in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with `this`.
When used with strings, Java's `+` operator will implicitly call `toString()` on any non-string operand.

This is how expressions like `"A" + 1` compile.

Comment: Incorrect. And primitives don't have a `toString()` method.

Comment: @Bohemian: They're auto-boxed first.

Comment: No they're not autoboxed. StringBuilder's `append(int)` is called, and that calls `AbstractStringBuilder`'s `append(int)` method, and that calls `Integer.getChars()` and that does the String building the hard way. No autoboxing anywhere.

Comment: @Bohemian Not according to [5.1.11 of the the spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.11)

Comment: Though in the case of two *literals* the compiler actually just deals with it and the result is stored in the constant_pool in the .class file (at least in java 7)

Comment: Heh, though looking at the bytecode what the *spec* says and what Oracle's JVM *does* seem to be two different things. Bad Oracle ... bad Oracle.

Comment: @BrianRoach AFAICT that's *converting*, ie casting eg `String s = (String)i`. String *concatenation* is (sounds like it could be) different to *conversion*

Comment: @BrianRoach although DavidWallace's comment to my answer seems to have found that it *should* be calling the toString() of the autoboxed Object. So much for the JLS :(

Comment: @Bohemian 5.18.1 explicitly states that string concatenation causes a conversion and points at 5.1.11. They literally violate the spec the way they're doing it, heh.

Answer (score 0):

in this line:

```
 "\nthis (with implicit toString() call): " + this;
```

The operator '+' works with two strings, java implicitly call to the toString() method to obtain the string representation of the object referenced by this. write "this" or "this.toString()" is totally equivalent.